# Gulp-concat doesnt work. There's no output file

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

Can't figure out why gulp-concat doesn't work correctly. When i try to compile my javascript it doesn't give me the output file. All the paths are correct. I tried to remove .pipe(concat()) and the .js file appeared in the correct folder. But the same code with concat() doesn't work.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  jade = require('gulp-jade-php'),
  concat = require('gulp-concat'),
  notify = require('gulp-notify'),
  cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin'),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
  uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
  autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

var path = {
  src: {
    styles: 'git/**/*.scss',
    scripts: 'git/**/scripts/*.js',
    jade: 'git/**/*.jade'
  },
  publicPath: "../",
  npm: {
    jquery: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    bootstrap: 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js',
        swiper: 'bower_components/swiper/dist/js/swiper.jquery.min.js'
  },
  watch: {
    styles: 'git/**/*.scss',
    scripts: 'git/**/*.js',
    jade: 'git/**/*.jade'
  }
};

var scriptPaths = [path.src.scripts, path.npm.jquery, path.npm.bootstrap, path.npm.swiper];

// Scripts //
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src(scriptPaths)
  .pipe(concat('script.js'))
  .pipe(notify({
    message: 'Javascript Success'
  }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.publicPath))
});

gulp.task('build:scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src(scriptPaths)
  .pipe(concat('script.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(rename({
    suffix: '.min'
  }))
  .pipe(notify({
    message: 'Javascript Success'
  }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.publicPath))
});

// Watch //
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(path.watch.styles, ['styles']);
  gulp.watch(path.watch.scripts, ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch(path.watch.jade, ['html']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'scripts', 'html']);
gulp.task('build', ['build:styles', 'build:scripts', 'html']);
```

Do you have any ideas why it doesn't work. I tried to remove node_modules and installed it again, but it didn't help

Comment: @stan done. I just posted the question accidentaly

Comment: scriptPaths should be an array of file paths, you have an array of objects. This could be your issue.